# Exception (SIGABRT) when opening on an iPad, unable to replicate.

Tags: ios, ios8

Apparently an App I submitted for review crashed twice on an iPad, with the following issue highlighted. I'm having trouble deciphering anything usable from this, if anyone's able to shed some light on this I'd appreciate it. I've attempted to replicate the issue using the simulator's but I've been unsuccessful. I don't understand how this could work on an iPhone, whilst testing, but not on the iPad.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195a8f270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195b2d224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195a06b14 abort + 108
3   Christmas                       0x0000000100101b90 0x1000f4000 + 56208
4   Christmas                       0x0000000100101744 0x1000f4000 + 55108
5   Christmas                       0x00000001000ff504 0x1000f4000 + 46340
6   Christmas                       0x00000001000ff218 0x1000f4000 + 45592
7   Christmas                       0x0000000100135088 0x1000f4000 + 266376
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188f6be3c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 512
9   UIKit                           0x00000001890099bc -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 796
10  UIKit                           0x00000001890093b8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 636
11  UIKit                           0x00000001890090d8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
12  UIKit                           0x0000000189009058 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 196
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188f51a28 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 568
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001888a9990 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 164
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001888a4560 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 316
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001888a4404 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001888a3c04 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 272
18  QuartzCore                      0x00000001888a3988 CA::Transaction::commit() + 432
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188f489fc _afterCACommitHandler + 152
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018475e148 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018475b0d4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018475b4b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001846891f0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
24  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d7eb5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
25  UIKit                           0x0000000188fba780 UIApplicationMain + 1484
26  Christmas                       0x0000000100103914 0x1000f4000 + 63764
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195976a04 start + 0
```

Comment: Look for information on symbolicatecrash.  It's an Xcode-related script for turning addresses in your app into readable symbols.  With that, the stack frames pointing to "Christmas" should make sense.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've managed to identify the crash is a result of it failing this statement. "if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])"